# GO:array/slice to regular string

Tags: arrays, go

I am sort of new to golang, and also kind of new to programming. And go has been very hard for me. This is one thing that always confuses me: data types. If you run this(not on the playground) then it will spit out:

```
./main.go:40: cannot use recorded (type string) as type SVC in append
```

and if I reverse the values in the append call, it will spit out:

```
./main.go:40: first argument to append must be slice; have string
```

What I am trying to do is grab all of the stuff in the home directory, append all of the values with the modifications to an array, then put the array into a file using ioutil. All I want(as of now) is to append the values to the slice in func record. Can anybody help?

```
package main

import "os"
import "io/ioutil"
import "fmt"

type SVC struct {
        key string
        val string
}

func main() {
        os.Chdir("../../../../../../..")
        var data, err = ioutil.ReadDir("home")
        checkerr(err)
        for _, data := range data {
                fmt.Println(data.Name())
        }
        os.Chdir("home/beanboybunny/repos/bux/go/src/bux")
}
func checkerr(err1 error) {
        if err1 != nil {
                fmt.Println("error")
        }
}
func writer(dataname string) {
        f := "var "
        uname := dataname
        q := " = VVC{\n"
        w := "  bux: 1,\n"
        e := "  op: true,\n"
        c := "}" 

        b2 := f + uname + q + w + e + c 
        record(b2)
}

func record(recorded string) {
        cache := []SVC{}
        record SVC := recorded 
        appenda := append(cache, recorded)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `type SVC struct` has two private string fields.  If you just want an array of strings you don't need the `SVC` type.

If you're just trying to build an array of strings with your specially formatted transform of the items in the home directory, here is a start showing the use of append and format strings: https://play.golang.org/p/eUKTKRxwfp

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    os.Chdir("../../../../../../..")
    var data, err = ioutil.ReadDir("home")
    checkerr(err)
    lines := []string{}
    for _, data := range data {
        fmt.Println(data.Name())
        lines = append(lines, buildLine(data.Name()))
    }
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(lines, "\n"))
    os.Chdir("home/beanboybunny/repos/bux/go/src/bux")
}

func checkerr(err1 error) {
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err1)
    }
}

func buildLine(dataname string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("var %s = VVC{\n bux: 1,\n op: true,\n}", dataname)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add meters to liters. So you can't append `string` type to a list of `SVC` records.

If you want `[]SVC` as output (*list of `SVC`*) you need to implement a parser that transform a string to an `SVC` object and append it.

If you want `[]string` as output you need to implement a serializer that transform an `SVC` to a string and append it.

How to do it is a separate question that is out of scope for this question.